# Creating a bar chart from datatable

Tags: c#, ado.net

I'm writing a console application that fetches data from database (SQL) and writes to an excel sheet. Now I want to add a chart in the workbook according to the datatable values. How can I create chart in the sheet before saving? How will I use dataset values to create chart?

Thank you.

Comment: This looks more lika a programming question then a DBA question, you should ask on stackoverflow instead of dba.SE

Comment: I believe this question is in intersection between programming and business intelligence. BI questions are welcome here. These question is equally applicable to stackoverflow

Answer (score 2):

If you are using csv , you can not do this. But if you are willing to use other tools like Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services or Crystal Reports you may do this.

- [SSRS Chart Example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964128%28v=sql.90%29.aspx), here [another one](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/36881/Microsoft-Reporting-Services-Sub-Reports-Charts-Pa) with code example.

If you can not install Reporting Services Server or do not want to, you can still use it for basic reporting purposes. Take a look at here,[Microsoft Reporting without SQL Server Reporting Services](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25222/Microsoft-Reporting-without-SQL-Server-Reporting-S).

Note that , I gave you examples for reporting services since it is easy to use out of box and in most cases free. But there are a lot of other tools exists which may be more suitable/powerful for your use case.